# Loading data from a file using member function

Tags: c++

The person class should have the following functions:
•   Constructor(s)
•   Destructor - optional
•   Get - read first name, last name, and age from an input stream
•   Put - write last name, first name, and age to an output stream

I was trying to implement the get() so that it could read the text from a file, but I'm kinda stuck.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "person.h";
using namespace std;

person::person()
{  
   fName = "Default";
   lName = "Default";
   age   = 0;
}

bool person::get(istream &in)
{ 
  in >> fName >> lName >> age;
  return(in.good());
}

// Output
void person::put(ostream &out)
{ 
  out << lName << fName << age;
}
```

person.h

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Person header.h
class person
{  public:
        person();                       // Empty constructor.
        bool get(istream &);            // Read input from file.
        void put(ostream &);            // Write to an output stream.

        // Operators to compare.
        bool operator < (person);       //lesser.
        bool operator > (person);       //greater.
        bool operator == (person);      //equal.

        string fName;                   //First Name.
        string lName;                   //Last Name.
        int age;                        //Age.
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

#include "person.h"

void main()
{ 
  int i,x;
  string name;
  fstream infile;
  person info[20];

  //Open File.
  cout << "Enter the file name: ";
  cin >> name;
  infile.open(name.data(),ios::in);


  // loop
  while (!infile.eof())
  {  

     if(infile.good())

        {
            for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            { 

              info[i].get(cin);
            }

        };

  }; 
  infile.close();
}
```

It freezes whenever I try to use get() to load input from a file to an array. However, it works when I do:

```
infile >> info[i].lName >> info[i].fName >> info[i].age;
```

Here is my data from the file.

```
Ann Christensen  70
Carlos Morales   68
David Bowman     45
Frank Bowman     37
John Bowman      30
Kathleen Gueller 34
Mark Bowman      42
Mark Bowman      13
Richard Bowman   47
Susan Cox        36
```

Thank you.

Comment: 10 persons in the list, attempt to read in 20 in a `for` cycle which doesn't test for the status of the input stream and/or the result returned by `get`

Comment: `get` function that doesn't test the status of the stream after each read.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Answer (score -1):

If I'm reading your code correctly, this is because you are calling `info[i].get(cin)`, while you wanted to do `info[i].get(infile)`. The way it is now, it tries to read input from the console, thus is "hanging".

Also, I believe the `for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)` loop is no good here. A better approach here would be to use a `vector` to hold your correctly read `person`s.

```
std::vector<person> info;
//...

// loop
while (!infile.eof())
{  
    if(infile.good())
    {
        person new_person;
        if (new_person.get(infile))
            info.push_back(new_person);
    }
}
```

Or even simpler:

```
person new_person;
while (new_person.get(infile))  //you can keep overwriting the object
    info.push_back(new_person); //because vector makes a copy of it
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong